# How to get the gain for this MOSFET amplifier?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, small-signal, common-drain

This is a common drain MOSFET amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvL8bc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is its small signal model at low frequency:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOvDzu.png)</sup>

I am at a loss as to how to find \$V_{\text{out}}/V_{\text{in}}\$. \$V_{\text{in}}\$, in this case, is just \$V_g\$ not \$V_{gs}\$ since the source node is not connected to ground.

**My analysis:**

Since all of the current source's current is going thru \$r_0\$ from \$V_{\text{out}}\$ to GND,

$$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{r_0}=V_{gs} \times g_m$$ or
$$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{r_0}=(V_{in}-V_{out}) \times g_m$$.
After some algebraic manipulation, you get
$$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}}=\frac{r_0 \times g_m}{1+r_0  \times g_m}$$

I know $$r_o \times g_m=\left(\frac{\delta I_d}{\delta V_{ds}}\right)^{-1} \times \frac{\delta I_d}{\delta V_{gs}}=\frac{\delta V_{ds}}{\delta V_{gs}}$$

I don't know what to do after this. My professor's solution says \$V_{\text{out}}/V_{\text{in}} = 1\$. How?

Comment: The circuit as drawn has zero gain. That is, the output is completely independent of the input. Are you sure you drew it right?

Comment: gm*ro is usually much much higher than 1

Comment: Vgs is just Vin, not Vin-Vout. Then you get vo/vi = gm*Ro. If Ro is 1/gm. you get gm/gm =1.

Answer (score 0):

Vgs = 5V so RsOn is low and you have a SOURCE follower ( or common drain ) with some unknown load resistance say 100x RdsOn which is missing between Source and Vss.

So it's a drain follower, like a unity gain emitter follower with a gain=<1 depending on load regulation, Roin and a DC bias above Vgs(th).

But a rather sloppy logic diagram with errors... tisk.

Other
_ - - 
Here is how I would make a 1GHz buffer Av =1 almost unity

I added Ciss and Rg to the model with very low RdsON Vt=1V and due to load regulation from Ron and insufficient Vgs bias from Vss the Vout DC is a bit more than -1V.

[image]

Go back and review your  common drain notes for details.